# Silent login with technical user

Tags: azure-ad-msal

We want to use a technical user in a mobile application (iOS). This user needs to access MS Graph API.

I currently find no method to acquire a token from mobile without any UI interaction.

Is there any way we can achieve this is a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of devices and operating systems (e.i. IoT) that do not provide a web browser, you can use the device code flow, which lets the user use another device (computer or mobile phone) to sign-in interactively. Here's more info on using [device code flow with msal](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Device-Code-Flow).

Using a mobile device, which is a public client, has many ways of acquiring a token (including silently, assuming a token is already in the cache), most of which involve a UI. Public clients are run on devices or desktop machines and are not trusted to safely keep application secrets. Here's more information on [public client applications](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Applications#publicclientapplication) for msal .NET, which supports Xamarin iOS.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It turned out that we need to find another way for our use case.

Comment: What's the use case?